# File Read in MIPS Assembly Stuck in Infinite Loop

Tags: assembly, text, file-io, io, mips

I am writing a program in MIPS to encrypt a simple text file. Currently I'm stuck because whenever I read in blocks of text, instead of stopping at the end of the file it seems to keep reading in infinite bytes until it rounds out of space. I'm not sure why this is happening, but v0 returns 0xffffffff bytes read. I'm wondering if somewhere in my program there is a logic error or if I'm using file read wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
        .include "SysCalls.asm"
        
        .eqv    $key            $a2
            .eqv    $filename   $a3 
        .eqv    $descriptor $t1
        .eqv    textBufSize 1024
        .eqv    maxKeySize  60
        .eqv    fnameSize   255
        .eqv    readOnly    0
        .eqv    writeOnlyCreate 1
        .eqv    writeOnlyAppend 9
        .eqv    sframe      16              
                            
        .data 
encryptOption:  .asciiz  "1: Encrypt the File \n"
decryptOption:  .asciiz  "2: Decrypt the File \n"
exitOption:     .asciiz  "3: Exit \n"

keyPrompt:  .asciiz  "Enter a key (up to 60 characters): \n"
filenamePrompt: .asciiz  "Enter a filename (up to 255 characters): \n"

notFound:   .asciiz  "File Error! \n"

filenameBuf:    .space   fnameSize
keyBuffer:  .space   maxKeySize
textBuffer:     .space   textBufSize
        
        .align  2
keySize:    .word   0
    
        .text
        
        .eqv    Encrypt     1
        .eqv    Decrypt     2
        .eqv    Exit        3
printMenu:  
    la  $a0, encryptOption
    li  $v0, SysPrintString
    syscall
    la  $a0, decryptOption
    li  $v0, SysPrintString
    syscall
    la  $a0, exitOption
    li  $v0, SysPrintString
    syscall
        
getMenuOption:  
    li  $v0, SysReadInt
    syscall
    beq     $v0, Encrypt, startEncrypt
    beq     $v0, Decrypt, startDecrypt  
    beq     $v0, Exit, exit
    j   getMenuOption
    
startEncrypt:
    la  $a0, filenamePrompt
    la  $a1, filenameBuf
    li  $a2, fnameSize
    jal getString
    
    li  $a1, readOnly
    li  $a2, 0   
    la  $a0, filenameBuf
    jal     openFile

    bltz    $descriptor, printMenu      # go to file error if it's not found

    la  $a0, keyPrompt
    la  $a1, keyBuffer
    li  $a2, maxKeySize
    jal getString
        
    beqz    $a3, fileError      # making sure key isn't empty (0 length) by checking # of bytes read
    sw  $a3, keySize
    
    la  $t0, textBuffer     # temp ptr to text
    la  $t1, keyBuffer      # temp ptr to key
    li  $t2, 0      # loading data counter w/ 0
    li  $t3, 0      # loading key counter
    lw  $t4, keySize
getData:
    move    $a0, $descriptor    # move the file descriptor to argument reg to pass during jal
    la  $a1, textBuffer
    li  $a2, textBufSize
    li  $t2, 0          # loading data counter w/ 0
    jal     readFile
    beq $a3, 0, printMenu

    
encrypt:
    beq     $t2, $a3, getData   # if read in 1024 bytes, get next data block
    beq     $t3, $t4, resetKey  # if read in full key, go to reset key data pointer
    lb  $s0, 0($t0)     # store first byte of text into $s0
    beq     $s0, '\n', skipNL   # if this byte is NL skip it and return
    lb  $s1, 0($t1)     # get next key byte
    addu    $s0, $s1, $s0       # encrypt s0 data with key
    sb  $s0, 0($t0)     # store encrypted data back into text buffer
    addi    $t0, $t0, 1     # increment text buffer data pointer
    addi    $t1, $t1, 1     # increment key buffer data pointer
    addi    $t2, $t2, 1     # increment data counter 
    addi    $t3, $t3, 1     # increment key counter 
    j   encrypt

resetKey:
    la  $t0, keyBuffer
    subu    $t3, $t3, maxKeySize 
    j   encrypt
    
skipNL:
    addi    $t0, $t0, 1
    addi    $t3, $t3, 1
    j   encrypt

startDecrypt:
    j   printMenu

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  void readFile(int descriptor, char[] buffer, int maxSize)    
#
#  - routine to open a file with name "filename"
#
#  input:  $a0 --> file descriptor
#      $a1 --> address of input buffer
#   `  $a2 --> max number of characters to read
#
#  return: $a3 --> number of bytes read in  
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
readFile:
    subi    $sp, $sp, 4 # reserving space on stack and preserving state                 
        sw  $ra, 0($sp)
        
        li  $v0, SysReadFile
    syscall
        
        move    $a3, $v0        
    lw  $ra, 0($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, 4    
    jr  $ra         # return to calling function
        

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  void openFile(string filename, int flags, int mode)  
#
#  - routine to open a file with name "filename"
#
#  input:  $a0 --> filename buffer - null terminated
#      $a1 --> flags
#   `  $a2 --> mode
#
#  return: $t1 --> file descriptor  
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
openFile:
    subi    $sp, $sp, sframe    # reserving space on stack and preserving state
    sw  $a0, 0($sp)                             
    sw  $a1, 4($sp)                         
    sw  $a2, 8($sp)                     
        sw  $ra, 12($sp)
        
    li  $v0, SysOpenFile    
    syscall
    move    $descriptor, $v0    # save file descriptor from v0  
    bltz    $v0, fileError      # go to file error if it's not found
    j   retOpenFile
    
fileError: 
    la  $a0, notFound
    li  $v0, SysPrintString
    syscall

retOpenFile:
    lw  $a0, 0($sp)     # restore state and remove stack frame
    lw  $a1, 4($sp) 
    lw  $a2, 8($sp)         
    lw  $ra, 12($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, sframe    
    jr  $ra         # return to calling function
                            
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  void getString(char[] buffer, int maxSize, String prompt)    
#
#  - routine to read in string and strip out ending "\n"
#
#  input:  $a0 --> prompt
#      $a1 --> location of where to store the string
#      $a2 --> max size of the string to read in
#
#  return: $a3 --> # of bytes stored in the "buffer"    
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
        .eqv    $aRetValue  $a3
        .eqv    $tPrompt    $t0 
        .eqv    $tCounter   $t1
        .eqv    $tBuffer    $t2
        .eqv    $tMaxSize   $t3
                
getString:
    subi    $sp, $sp, sframe    # reserving space on stack and preserving state
    sw  $a0, 0($sp)                                 
    sw  $a1, 4($sp)                             
    sw  $a2, 8($sp)                     
        sw  $ra, 12($sp)

    move    $tPrompt, $a0
    move    $tBuffer, $a1
    move    $tMaxSize, $a2
    
    li  $v0, SysPrintString
    syscall
    
    move    $a0, $tBuffer
    move    $a1, $tMaxSize
    li  $v0, SysReadString
    syscall
        
# removes NL character from the end of the string and replace it will null  
            
    move    $a0, $tBuffer       # put filename address in a0 for cleaning
    li  $tCounter, 0        # initializing counter to 0
nextChar:   
    lb  $t0, 0($a0)
    addi    $tCounter, $tCounter, 1     # incrementing counter      
    bne     $t0, '\n', skipChar     # if it is not new line character, then skip the character 
    li  $t0, 0          # if it is new line character, change it to null terminator
    sb  $t0, 0($a0)     # putting the null terminator into place where NL is
    j   retGetString        # return to caller
        
skipChar:   
    addi    $a0, $a0, 1     # increment filename data pointer
    j   nextChar
    
retGetString:
    move    $aRetValue, $tCounter   # return the number of bytes in the string buffer
    lw  $a0, 0($sp)     # restore state and remove stack frame
    lw  $a1, 4($sp)     
    lw  $a2, 8($sp)     
    lw  $ra, 12($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, sframe    
    jr  $ra         # return to calling function

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  EXIT from Program
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------                 
exit: 
    li  $v0, SysExit
        syscall
```

[image: The error]

[image: registers]

Comment: You aliased `$descriptor` to `$t1` which then clashes with other use such as `la  $t1, keyBuffer`. Note that `0xffffffff` is `-1` and indicates an error (namely that the desciptor is invalid) and `readFile` should not have worked the first time around either. So the whole reading multiple blocks and hitting end of file is a red herring.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info, that at least narrows things down. Hopefully fixing the data clashes will allow me to read in the file correctly.

Comment: Also, you might try getting piece parts working first in their own program, then put together into your project.  What I'm saying is that is a lot of code (to debug) just to read a file.

Comment: @ErikEidt That's a good idea although I'm not sure if I have time at this point. Unfortunately fixing the clashes didn't work. Now I'm not getting an error on opening the file, but when reading it reads 0 bytes.